# Carousel not sliding in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a carousel using boot and it won't slide. When I tried the code on an online editor it ran and was able to slide. For some reason it will show the picture but I cannot goto the next pic. Plz help!!

```css
.navbar-brands {
 float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.menu {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: #181717;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

a {
 color: #181717;
}

.carousel{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.carousel .item img{
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Guardians | Home</title>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brands" href="#"><img src="jamallogo2.png"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li id="active" class="menu"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="#ABOUT">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="#RESEARCH">RESEARCH</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="#DONATE">DONATE</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
     <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
     <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel"></li>
    </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active" alt="slide1">
                <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/c5f9quupn/leopard.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item" alt="slide2">
                <img src="http://s15.postimg.org/g1pqxnl47/gorilla.jpg?noCache=1440526418">
            </div>
            <div class="item" alt="slide3">
                <img src="http://s15.postimg.org/wgjoa833f/turtle.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also have this problem inmy chrome when i view the page: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: You should add a reference to jQuery before the bootstrap JS

Comment: thanks luc! I added a jQuery reference and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You should add a reference to jQuery before the bootstrap JS. Bootstrap requires jQuery, so you have to load it before you load Bootstrap